# List ALL items from table1 and fill in info from table2 where there is a match

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I need to list all items from table 1 and show the matching records from table 2. Table 1 contains 6 rows with categories. Table 2 contains users and there matching categories. Some users can be part of more than one category, so can appear more than once in this table.

This is how my tables look like :

#### Table 1:

```
- catID
- categoryname
```

#### Table 2:

```
- userID
- catID
- catDetails
```

I already tried with joins, unions.. and ended up with the  query below.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 one , table2 two
WHERE two.userID = 1  AND one.catID = two.catID
```

I expect something like :

```
catID1 - userID1
catID2
catID3 - userID1
catID4 - userID1 - catdetails1
catID4 - userID1 - catdetails2
catID4 - userID1 - catdetails3
catID4 - userID1 - catdetails4
catID5
```

**(user has 1 and 3 once, and 4x4)**

But I get :

```
catID1 - userID1
catID3 - userID1
catID4 - userID1 - catdetails1
catID4 - userID1 - catdetails2
catID4 - userID1 - catdetails3
catID4 - userID1 - catdetails4
```

**catID2 & catID5 do not display as wanted.**

How can I make sure that all categories are visible, even if there is no matching data for the selected user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LEFT JOIN,`

The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all records from the left table (table1), and the matched records from the right table (table2). The result is NULL from the right side if there is no match.

[image]

```
SELECT * FROM table1 one 
LEFT JOIN table2 two
ON one.catID = two.catID
AND two.userID = 1
```

**Demo:**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/313798/4

**Output**

```
catID   categoryname    userID  catID   catDetails
1       CAT1            1       1       (null)
2       CAT2            (null)  (null)  (null)
3       CAT3            1       3       (null)
4       CAT4            1       4       catdetails2
4       CAT4            1       4       catdetails3
4       CAT4            1       4       catdetails4
4       CAT4            1       4       catdetails1
5       CAT5            (null)  (null)  (null)
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.catID, t2.userID, t2.catDetails
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.userID = 1  AND t2.catID = t1.catID
```

Unlike `(INNER) JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN` does not filter out records in `table1` that have no corresponding record in `table2`.